# How do i change the create_initial_grid function so the first positions of the cells is decided by a list of coordinates instead of a random function

Tags: python, conways-game-of-life

Content of coordinate file `katt.txt`:

```
3 4
3 7
4 4
4 5
4 6
4 7
5 3
5 8
6 3
6 5
6 6
6 8
7 3
7 8
8 4
8 5
8 6
8 7
```

Code:

```
import time
import random
    
  
with open('katt.txt') as f:
    numbers = [int(elem) for elem in f.read().split()]

coordinates = zip(numbers[::2], numbers[1::2])

def create_initial_grid(rows, cols, coordinates):
    return [[1 if (x, y) in coordinates else 0 for y in range(cols)]
            for x in range(cols)]

  

def print_grid(rows, cols, grid, generation):

    #Prints to console the Game of Life grid


    # A single output string is used to help reduce the flickering caused by printing multiple lines
    output_str = ""

    # Compile the output string together and then print it to console
    output_str += "Generation {0} - To exit the program early press <Ctrl-C>\n\r".format(generation)
    for row in range(rows):
        for col in range(cols):
            if grid[row][col] == 0:
                output_str += "-"
            else:
                output_str += "*"
        output_str += "\n\r"
    print(output_str, end=" ")


def create_next_grid(rows, cols, grid, next_grid):
    
    #Analyzes the current generation of the Game of Life grid and determines what 
    #cells live and die in the next generation of the Game of Life grid.
  

    for row in range(rows):
        for col in range(cols):
            # Get the number of live cells adjacent to the cell at grid[row][col]
            live_neighbors = get_live_neighbors(row, col, rows, cols, grid)

            # If the number of surrounding live cells is < 2 or > 3 then we make the cell at grid[row][col] a dead cell
            if live_neighbors < 2 or live_neighbors > 3:
                next_grid[row][col] = 0
            # If the number of surrounding live cells is 3 and the cell at grid[row][col] was previously dead then make
            # the cell into a live cell
            elif live_neighbors == 3 and grid[row][col] == 0:
                next_grid[row][col] = 1
            # If the number of surrounding live cells is 3 and the cell at grid[row][col] is alive keep it alive
            else:
                next_grid[row][col] = grid[row][col]


def get_live_neighbors(row, col, rows, cols, grid):
   
    #Counts the number of live cells surrounding a center cell at grid[row][cell].


    life_sum = 0
    for i in range(-1, 2):
        for j in range(-1, 2):
            # Make sure to count the center cell located at grid[row][col]
            if not (i == 0 and j == 0):
                # Using the modulo operator (%) the grid wraps around
                life_sum += grid[((row + i) % rows)][((col + j) % cols)]
    return life_sum


def grid_changing(rows, cols, grid, next_grid):
  
    #Checks to see if the current generation Game of Life grid is the same as the next generation Game of Life grid.
 

    for row in range(rows):
        for col in range(cols):
            # If the cell at grid[row][col] is not equal to next_grid[row][col]
            if not grid[row][col] == next_grid[row][col]:
                return True
    return False


def get_integer_value(prompt, low, high):
   
    #Asks the user for integer input and between given bounds low and high.
  

    while True:
        try:
            value = int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("Input was not a valid integer value.")
            continue
        if value < low or value > high:
            print("Input was not inside the bounds (value <= {0} or value >= {1}).".format(low, high))
        else:
            break
    return value


def run_game():
   
    #Asks the user for input to setup the Game of Life to run for a given number of generations.
    

    # Get the number of rows and columns for the Game of Life grid
    rows = get_integer_value("Enter the number of rows (10-30): ", 10, 30)
    cols = get_integer_value("Enter the number of cols (10-30): ", 10, 30)

    # Get the number of generations that the Game of Life should run for
    generations = get_integer_value("Enter the number of generations (1-100000): ", 1, 100000)
    

    # Create the initial Game of Life grids
    current_generation = create_initial_grid(rows, cols,coordinates)
    next_generation = create_initial_grid(rows, cols,coordinates)

    # Run Game of Life sequence
    gen = 1
    for gen in range(1, generations + 1):
        if not grid_changing(rows, cols, current_generation, next_generation):
            break
        print_grid(rows, cols, current_generation, gen)
        create_next_grid(rows, cols, current_generation, next_generation)
        time.sleep(1 / 5.0)
        current_generation, next_generation = next_generation, current_generation

    print_grid(rows, cols, current_generation, gen)
    input("Press <Enter> to exit.")


# Start the Game of Life
run_game()
```

Answer (score 0):

With `coordinates` being an Iterable of `(x, y)` tuples indicating where your grid should be `1` (`0` otherwise), just write something like:

```
def create_initial_grid(rows, cols, coordinates):
    return [[1 if (x, y) in coordinates else 0 for y in range(cols)]
            for x in range(rows)]

create_initial_grid(2, 3, [(0, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1)])
# [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]]
```

Assuming your text file consists of the alternating `x` and `y` coordinates of living cells you can read the coordinates with:

```
with open('coordinates.txt') as f:
    numbers = [int(elem) for elem in f.read().split()]

coordinates = list(zip(numbers[::2], numbers[1::2]))
```

or even shorter:

```
with open('coordinates.txt') as f:
    coordinates = [tuple(map(int, line.split()))
                   for line in f.readlines()]
```

Comment: Thank you for anwering, but i think you misunderstood my problem. I have a txt file with x and y coordinates and i want a function that converts those coordinates into the first iteration of living cells, the convertion from the txt file is the issue.

Comment: Really appreciate the help! I've tried to implement you changes as shown in the code above, but the result it gives me is a complacently dead first generation, no cells have been given life. Am i doing it wrong?

Comment: My bad. You should be using `list(zip(...))` instead of `zip(...)` in this case as `zip` returns an iterator that is consumed after the first call to `__contains__()` (implicitely called by `if (x, y) in coordinates`. 

Use one of the updated versions instead.

Comment: Thats amazing! Now the file implemented first generation works! But it only runs one generation and then stops, did the changes make something in the Run game of life sequence stop working, so annoying! You've helped me so much thank you!

Comment: For some reason you assign `current_generation` and `next_generation` the same starting position. Hence `not grid_changing(...)` is `True` and you break out of the loop in the first iteration.

Comment: What i don't understand is how the first version of this code, with the function that randomly selected the first gen cells, how that could produce a working game of life but now it doesn't. If you could help me get this to work i would be forever grateful

Comment: If you initialize both of them randomly they will most certainly differ. Not so If you assign them the same position.

Comment: Ok i see, so without the random function the rest of the code doesn't rally work. Is there any work around where i don't have to redo everything you think?

Comment: It does only require little changes, but SO is not a homework service. It appears to me that you haven't written any (or if only very little) of the code by yourself and I think you barely understand what it does. There is no use in me spoon-feeding you the solution, you should be able to figure that out on your own if  you want to learn.

Comment: I understand, I'll keep on working. Thank you for the help